# Are there Wolter telescope lenses for consumer cameras?

Tags: optics, astronomy, telescopes, camera, astrophotography

Wolter telescopes are used for x-ray astronomy. However, I see no reason why they couldn't be used for visible light as well.

How would a visible image look when taken through a Wolter telescope?

Are there Wolter-type attachments for consumer cameras available?

Comment: Sounds like a good home experiment (although some machining may be required). Seems unlikely that there are any Wolter lenses for cameras readily available.

Comment: Yes, a bunch of polished tubes or sheet metal might do. If I had some time I'd do it myself. I would expect that they don't suffer from chromatic aberration at least, but the FOV should just be a few degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflective optics have a strong aberation when the image is off the optical axis, therefore they are ok for telescopes that have a very narrow field of view but not ok for regular cameras.

You should be able to purchase a Schwarzschild objective (operating on a similar as the Wolter) ($$$) and mount it on a camera

Comment: Very nice, thank you.